# Password/IP/etc. detector in source code

Tags: windows, software-development, source-code

I am looking for a program that can scan some source code and spot the presence of any confidential information such as password, IP, port, username, etc. If possible, Windows 7 and free, but my priority is the quality of the detection. As often in information retrieval, high recall and the precision is better than high precision and low recall.

Comment: How would you detect passwords (except by giving the program the password)?

Comment: E.g. with the context, such as variable names or library functions that take password as arguments.